# Sorting words according to length in textarea using html & javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div  align="center">
    <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" id="sorter3" name="sorter3" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" wrap="hard"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" value="words in Asc" onClick="SortWords()">                  
</div>
```

This is my html page for that corresponding javascript is:

```
function SortWords(){
    var inputvalues=document.getElementById("sorter3").value.split("");   
    inputvalues.sort();       
    //alert(inputvalues)
    alert(inputvalues[0])
    document.getElementById("sorter3").value=inputvalues;       
}
```

it is showing the output based on words initials but i need output based on length:
example: when i enter some thing in text area as : welcome to javascriptworld it is a independent langauage, expected output is : smallest word is 'a' and longest word is 'javascriptworld' can anybody help me how to do this

Comment: Hi, I would remove all symbols from the text first i.e. commas, hyphens, quotes, etc. Then I would split it by spaces i.e. `split(" ") ` and then I would iterate through each word determining it's length by simply using [word.length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `sort` your inputvalues array(using `split(' ')` instead of `split('')`) based on the string-length of individual elements.

```
var inputvalues=document.getElementById("sorter3").value.split(" ");   
inputvalues.sort(function(x, y) {return x.length>y.length;});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/S2fzq/3/)

Comment: thankyou tewathia your DEMO program working properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change your

```
split("");
```

to

```
split(" ");
```

That way it will divide the string using the spaces rather than splitting it into each individual character.

As for the sort, if you send it a function as a parameter, it'll sort using the function as the comparison type. Maybe something like this (untested):

```
.sort(function (a, b) { return a.length - b.length; } );
```

The rest should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: i changed but that is not showing differently,i enter input as: welcome to javascriptworld in practice point, for that i need output as alerts smallest word is in to and longest word is :javascriptworld

Comment: Well you need to reassign your inputValues variable to the newly sorted one like "inputvalues = inputvalues.sort();"

Comment: @Maxwell'sDemon I don't think that's required, the `sort` method modifies the original array automatically

Comment: @tewathia Quite right. I've since tested this and it works for me. I don't know what's up.

Comment: for the same how can we sort numbers,eg:input as 22,98,1,104,32 for that how can we get output as smallest word is 1 and longest word is 104

Comment: @user3089855 You'd probably just use the same sort function but cast the number to a string: .sort(function (a, b) { return a.toString().length - b.toString().length; } );