# Sorting numbers according to length in textarea using html & javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 <div align="right">
     <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" id="sorter2" name="sorter2"  rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" wrap="hard"></textarea><br>     
     <input type="button" value="Numbers in Asc" onClick="SortNumbers()">           
 </div>
```

This is my html page for that i'm writing javascript as:

```
function SortNumbers(){
var arr=document.getElementById("sorter2").value.split(",");  
arr.sort();
alert(arr)
document.getElementById("sorter2").value=arr; }
```

for this i'm sorting numbers,eg: when enter 9,8,7,143,2,96 expected output as smallest number is 2 and longest word is 143 how can i do this ,can anybody help me thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you mean a natural sort where 2 comes before 10, and not length, as that usually means the number of characters that make it up

Comment: I'm very puzzled, because when I put your code in a jsfiddle, it works as expected, at least in Chrome.

Comment: Are you the same person asking this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396608/sorting-words-according-to-length-in-textarea-using-html-javascript It isn't clear what you mean by sorting according to length. What is your desired output from `9,8,7,143,2,96` for example?

Comment: that is not actually by length but based on lowest and highest numbers,could you give me the logic plz

Comment: Actually What do you  want? To sort it based on value or by length?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort(function(x,y){ 
  return x.toString().length > y.toString().length || // sort by length
  x > y; // and by its value
})
```

Comment: i believe he means doing a natural sort and not actually by the number of characters that make up the number

Comment: True, but if you test it out, it produces the natural order :) I just wanted to be expressive(instead of a-b)

Comment: Yes until you start adding in non whole numbers http://jsfiddle.net/UCva9/1/, but then again op isnt being clear on what he actually means so :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function SortNumbers() {
            var arr = document.getElementById("sorter2").value.split(",");                
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if((+arr[i])<(+arr[j])){
                    var temp=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=temp;
                }
                }
            }
            alert(arr)
            document.getElementById("sorter2").value = arr;
        }
```

> +arr[i] is used instead of parseInt(arr[i])

In this case you will get your numbers sorted and the result will be
2,7,8,9,96,143